# Argument of type '"combined"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormatFn'

Tags: typescript, winston, morgan

I am trying to use morgan along with winston logger. I am getting the following error. I have used the combined preset formats. i then want to log the request using my logger.

> [ts] Argument of type '"combined"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormatFn'.

```
app.use(morgan("combined" {
    stream(meta: any) {
       this.log.info("Request served", meta);
    },
    objectMode: true,
}));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the second object passed to the function does not match the type declared for it, which is `morgan.Options`. Because of this the compiler moves past the overload with `'combine'` as an argument and ultimately, when finding no overload matched, will choose the last overload to report the error on, giving a rather confusing error message.

The object literal you pass in does not match `morgan.Options` because `stream` should be of type `interface StreamOptions { write(str: string): void;}` and field `objectMode` does not exist on `morgan.Options` at all (al least not in the stock version with no augmentations, I did not install `Winston`)

The code below passes the compiler checks (note I did not actually run this code, I am not familiar with `morgan` just providing help with the typescript type error):

```
morgan('combined', {
    stream: {
        write: (meta: any) => {
           this.log.info("Request served", meta);
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: That makes sense, this seemed to solve my problem but i have a followup question in that `this.log` is undefined inside this object function. ` Cannot read property 'info' of undefined\nTypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined`

Comment: @Kay wops, yes since you want `this` from the declaration context best use an arrow function. Edited

Comment: Ty you so much. Fixed!